# Android - Retrofit Gson- How to parse JSON String to object at a JSON key in JSON response?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

This my JSON response:

```
{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test",
      "content": "{\"type\": \"status\", \"text\": \"Lorem ipsum dummy text.\", \"id\": 1}"
}
```

These are model structures:

```
class TestModel {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Content content;
}

class Content {
    public int id;
    public String status;
    public String text;
}
```

I want to parse content's value directly into my Content model object using Retrofit and GsonConvertor. But currently, I am parsing it as a String value than by using Gson.fromJson() convert to my Content model object. Is there any solution to get my expected result?

When I used to parse it using GsonConverterFactory, Retrofit gives callback in onFailure method with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 4 column 19 path $.data[0].content
```

Comment: directly pass the model class in retrofit

Comment: @ColdFire: I'm doing this, but I want to convert String value directly to my Content model. In response, I got string value on content key.

Comment: Why is the "content" value in your response a string? This does not follow the JSON standard, which is why adding a `GsonConverterFactory` to your `Retrofit` instance does not give you the results you want. The correct JSON format would return "content" as a JSON object, and not a string. Do you have any control over the JSON response?

Comment: @MA13 : Go with Bryan .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the JSON response, it is not in the [correct JSON format](http://json.org/example.html). The `"content"` field should be an object, not a string:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "content": {
        "type": "status",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dummy text.",
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

This will allow either `gson.fromJson(response, TestModel.class)` or `RetroFit` with a `GsonConverterFactory` to parse your response correctly into the corresponding object.

---

Of course, this only applies if you have the ability to change the JSON response you are receiving. If not, first make sure the person who *is* in control of the response knows that they are doing it *wrong*. If nothing changes, then you should be able to work around this by changing the `content` in `TestModel` to a `String`:

```
class TestModel {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String content;
}

class Content {
    public int id;
    public String type;
    public String text;
}
```

Then parsing each object separately:

```
TestModel testModel = gson.fromJson(response, TestModel.class);
Content content = gson.fromJson(testModel.content, Content.class);
```

---

If the response cannot be changed, another option is to create a [`TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for your `Content` object:

```
public class ContentAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Content> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Content value) throws IOException {
        // TODO: Writer implementation
    }

    @Override
    public Content read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if(in.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
            return fromJson(in.nextString());
        } else {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then add the `TypeAdapter` to your GSON implementation:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Content.class, new ContentAdapter()).create();
```

Comment: The response is correct. Server end guy doesn't want to create another table for `Content`. So, he stores this value in string format. This is the main problem, the value of the content key is JSON string. Right now, I'm converting this string to my Content object like `Content content = gson.fromJson(testModel.content, Content.class);` but I want it to convert by GsonConverterFactory in retrofit response parsing. I don't want to convert it using `gson.fromJson()`.

Comment: @MA13 The JSON format is most certainly *not* correct. Even if the "content" is stored as a `string`, that `string` should be serialized as a JSON object, not as `string`. I do not know what language the response API is written in, but assuming it is PHP; the server side should call `json_decode(content)` before passing it to the array that eventually gets encoded.

Comment: I cannot do anything with the response. I want a solution or a hack in the Android side,

Comment: @MA13 If the response cannot be changed, the solution is what I posted after the break. You have to deserialize the `Content` object separately. You can also register a `TypeAdapter` for the `Content` object with your `Gson` object, which is doing the same thing, but now Gson will do it automatically.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz You are correct, it is perfectly *valid* JSON, but that does not mean it is *correct* JSON. What I am saying is that the "content" field is *not* a JSON object, it is a string. For a JSON parser (such as GSON) to generate an *object*, it must receive a JSON object, *not* a string.

Comment: @Bryan I think you sure. Thanks for good pointing I missed the point too !

Comment: @Bryan Thanks.  TypeAdapter has resolved my problem but when I'm using `fromJson(in.nextString());` it will throw JsonSyntaxException. So, I have changed it to `Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.fromJson(value, ContentModel.class);`. Now it can parse my string value directly into my Content object.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using retrofit version 2.1.0, in this version you can choose the parsers of your choice, but in the previous version Gson was inbuilt parser. I assume you need to use Gson. for that you have to set `converterFactory` as `GsonConverterFactory`, example is given below.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

This will add Gson as your json parser.

Check out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/) tutorial. also read the documentation [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Dont forget to add this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using retrofit version 2.1.0 and GsonConverterFactory. It will return content key value as String, not my Content model object. And when I used to parse in my Content model object then it will give an exception. I have updated my question with the exception. BTW, why to add 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2' as dependency when using 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2' ?

Comment: Paste your server response too

Comment: Response without exception or with the exception?

Comment: I have already posted the normal response. What else you need to know?

Comment: Oke, I can see you have variable status in your model but the actual json key is type, any how thats not the issue

Answer (score -2):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class Parser {
        public static List<TestModel> JsonParser(String JsonString) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(content);
                List<TestModel > arrayList = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    TestModel  model = new TestModel();
                    model.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id")));
                    model.setName(obj.getString("name"));


    JSONArray contentArray = newJSONArray(obj.getString("content")));
                        JSONObject obj1 = contentArray.getJSONObject(1);
                        Content content = new Content();

                        content.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj1.getString("id")));
                        content.setStatus(obj1.getString("status"));
                        content.setText(obj1.getString("text"));


                    model.setContent(content);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                }
                return arrayList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
   class TestModel {
//Generate Setter Getter for all properties
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Content content;
}

class Content {
//Generate Setter Getter for all properties
    public int id;
    public String status;
    public String text;
}
```

Comment: I don't want this mechanism. I'm using retrofit with GsonConverterFactory. So, I need a mechanism which uses both libraries, not directly JsonObject or JsonArray class.